# FOLLOW Set of grammar having left factoring eliminated

Tags: context-free-grammar

I wonder what the FOLLOW set of a certain NonTerminal is, when the left-recursion of a grammar is eliminated, like in the following example grammar.

let's assume this grammar

```
1 E → T E’
2 E’→ + T E’ 
3 E’→ ε
4 T → F T’
5 T’→ * F T’
6 T’→ ε
7 F → ( E ) 
8 F → id
```

### Example 1:

Let's first take a look at the part row 4 - row 8

```
4 T → F T’
5 T’→ * F T’
6 T’→ ε
7 F → ( E ) 
8 F → id
```

Is it correct, that FOLLOW(F) in this context is... ?

{*}

Explanation:

1. If T' repeats, then F is followed by +. If, on the other hand, T' expands to ε, F is followed by ε.

### Example 2:

When we broaden the context and look at the whole grammar, is it correct, that the complete FOLLOW-Set of F for this grammar is... ?

-> {'+', '*', ')', '$'}

Explanation:

1. Look at line 5. If T' repeats, then F is followed by '*'. If, on the other hand, T' expands to ε, F is followed by ε. Thus the rule is to add FOLLOW(T') to FOLLOW(F).

-> {'*'}

2. If T' in row 4 again expands to ε, then the rule is to add FOLLOW(T) to FOLLOW(F).
3. If E' in line 2 expands to T' again, then T is followed by +. If E' expands to ε, then T is followed by ε. Again the Rule "Add FOLLOW(E') to FOLLOW(T) applies

-> {'+'}

4. It applies the same as in <2>. If E' in line 1 expands to ε, the Rule "Add FOLLOW(E) to FOLLOW(T)." Which is

-> {')'}

Yours sincerely

von Spotz

EDIT:

Corrected according to the answer ot rici that FOLLOW-Sets do not contain 'ε'. That's what the rule

```
If A -> αB, add FOLLOW(A) to FOLLOW(B)
```

is for.

Also rici's hint, that Follow of T is E, as stated in Example 2: (4) and thus also the accepting symbol '$' belongs to Follow(F).

Comment: Hello rici, if I remove the epislon-transitions, is it then correct ?

Comment: Yep that was my question. Could I make  it the accepted answer ?

Comment: Ok, made it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FOLLOW(F) is `{'+', '*', ')', $}` (where `$` is the end-marker).

Follow sets never include ε. You need to take ε into account when you compute FOLLOW, but you don't add it to any FOLLOW set.